# How to copy last subfolder in matlab by command

Tags: matlab, file, path, directory, copy

I have a problem to copy subfolder and its contents by matlab. My folder includes many levels of subfolder. And I want to copy last folder that include the file to other path. For example, A includes subfolder B, and in the folder B has folder C, folder C includes folder D, and folder D stores file 1 and file 2 (I call folder D that is last folder). I want to copy folder D and its files (file 1 and file 2 to other folder). Could you help me to do it by matlab code? I am using window 
Thank you so much

```
Folder A
|_sub folder B
  |_sub folder C
    |_sub folder D
      |_file 1
      |_file 2


%%%%%%%%%%%%%Function%%%%%%%%%%%%
function copysubfolder(source_A, destination)

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
function copysubfolder(source_A, destination)

OS = 'windows'; %// OP has mentioned Windows as his OS
paths = genpath(source_A);
if strcmp(OS,'windows')
    %// On Windows GENPATH separates paths with semicolons
    ind1 = strfind(paths(1:end-1),';');
else
    %// On Linux at least, not sure about other OSs, GENPATH separates paths with colons
    ind1 = strfind(paths(1:end-1),':');
end
copyfile(paths(ind1(end)+1:end-1),destination);

return;
```

Comment: I try to used your code by copysubfolder('Folder A','Test'). But it appears error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
logicals.

Error in copysubfolder (line 10)
copyfile(paths(ind1(end)+1:end),destination);"

Comment: Is 'Folder A' is a directory in your current working directory? If not, you need to give the full path to it.

Comment: Yes. Folder A is my current folder. But It is still error. I debug I see that ind1 is null, although paths is successful

Comment: @Davakar: I put full path and this is new error "Error using copyfile
No matching files were found.

Error in copysubfolder (line 10)
copyfile(paths(ind1(end)+1:end),destination);". What is problem?

Comment: @user3336190 The previous errors were because I developed my code on Linux and on it GENPATH generates path with ":" as compared to ";" on Windows. Edited my code accordingly. Let me know if it works this time!